# Why is my MVVM program not communicating properly?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I am making a WPF application that is a CRUD-like app for a remote MySQL database. It has a class to connect and load in contexts from the database. As far as I can tell from the rest of the solution it is working as intended. However, I am taking my first crack at using MVVM project architecture and I'm running into some problems. Right now, I want to make some views for the data and I'm gonna focus on CompanyModel, CompanyView and CompanyViewModel for the purposes of this post.

[Here is my project structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bpm5w.png)

Below is my MainViewModel.cs.

```
class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public RelayCommand CompanyViewCommand { get; set; }
        public RelayCommand DiscoveryViewCommand { get; set; }
        public CompanyViewModel CompanyVM { get; set; }
        public DiscoveryViewModel DiscoveryVM { get; set; }
        private object _currentView;

        public object CurrentView
        {
            get { return _currentView; }
            set
            {
                _currentView = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            // Connect to the database
            dataContext context = new dataContext();
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                // Waiting for Database to connect
                await context.Database.CanConnectAsync(new CancellationToken());
            });

            // Instantiate the ViewModels
            CompanyVM = new CompanyViewModel();
            DiscoveryVM = new DiscoveryViewModel();

            // Set the default ViewModel
            CurrentView = CompanyVM;

            // Make the command for the CompanyView
            CompanyViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
            {
                _ = CompanyVM.loadCompanies();
                CurrentView = CompanyVM;
            });

            // Make the command for the...
            DiscoveryViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
            {
                CurrentView = DiscoveryVM;
            });
        }
    }
```

Here is my CompanyViewModel.cs

```
internal class CompanyViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        // Declare instance variables
        private DataTable _myData;
        private MYSQLDAL.Models.dataContext _context;

        // Make the data grid property
        private ObservableCollection<CompanyModel> companies;
        public ObservableCollection<CompanyModel> Companies
        {
            get { return companies; }
            set
            {
                companies = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Companies));
            }
        }


        public List<CompanyModel> data { get; private set; }

        public CompanyViewModel()
        {
            // Make the model
            Task task = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await loadCompanies();
            });

            // My data
            while (!task.IsCompleted)
                Thread.Sleep(50);
            _myData = new DataTable();
        }

        public async Task loadCompanies()
        {
            using (var dataContext = new dataContext())
            {
                // Construct the search query
                IQueryable<CompanyModel> companyQuery = 
                    (IQueryable<CompanyModel>)(from company 
                                               in dataContext.Companies
                                               select new
                                               {
                                                    ID = company.Id,
                                                    Name = company.Name,
                                                    Address = company.Address,
                                                    Postal = company.Postal,
                                                    Location = company.City + ", " + company.Province,
                                                    Created = company.CreateDate
                                               });
                List<CompanyModel> results = await companyQuery.ToListAsync();
                Companies = new ObservableCollection<CompanyModel>(results);
            }
        }
    }
```

Below is my CompanyModel.cs

```
class CompanyModel //: ObservableObject
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Postal { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    }
```

Below is my CompanyView.xaml (note: this is in a UserControl)

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.25*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1.5*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.3*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Title of the view -->
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                   Text="Company View"
                   Foreground="Black"
                   FontSize="28"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Margin="0"
                   FontFamily="\Fonts\#Futura"
                   FontWeight="Medium"/>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15,0,0,0"/>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <DataGrid x:Name="companyDataGrid"
                      IsReadOnly="True"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Companies, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID"
                                        MinWidth="35"
                                        Width="0.1*"
                                        Binding="{Binding ID}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"
                                        MinWidth="200"
                                        Width="2*"
                                        Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address"
                                        MinWidth="150"
                                        Width="*"
                                        Binding="{Binding Address}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Postal/Zip"
                                        MinWidth="150"
                                        Width="*"
                                        Binding="{Binding Postal}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Location"
                                        MinWidth="175"
                                        Width="1.5*"
                                        Binding="{Binding Location}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Country"
                                        MinWidth="150"
                                        Width="*"
                                        Binding="{Binding Country}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Created"
                                        MinWidth="150"
                                        Width="*"
                                        Binding="{Binding Created}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2"
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Margin="0,10,0,10"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Border Width="110"
                    Height="30">
                <Border.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                                         EndPoint="1,2">
                        <GradientStop Color="#849cc4"
                                      Offset="0.0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#6c89b2"
                                      Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.Background>

                <Border.Clip>
                    <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="10"
                                       RadiusY="10"
                                       Rect="0,0,110,30"/>
                </Border.Clip>

                <Grid>
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock Text="Add Company"
                                   Foreground="Black"
                                   FontSize="14"
                                   TextAlignment="Center"
                                   FontFamily="\Fonts\#Futura"
                                   FontWeight="Medium"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Border>

            <Border Width="110"
                    Height="30"
                    Margin="15,0,0,0">
                <Border.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                                         EndPoint="1,2">
                        <GradientStop Color="#5bc3ff"
                                      Offset="0.0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#3aa0ff"
                                      Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.Background>

                <Border.Clip>
                    <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="10"
                                       RadiusY="10"
                                       Rect="0,0,110,30"/>
                </Border.Clip>

                <Grid>
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock Text="Edit Company"
                                   Foreground="Black"
                                   FontSize="14"
                                   TextAlignment="Center"
                                   FontFamily="\Fonts\#Futura"
                                   FontWeight="Medium"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Here is my ObservableObject.cs

```
    internal class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? name = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
```

Here is my MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private readonly MainViewModel _mainViewModel;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _mainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
            DataContext = _mainViewModel;
        }
    }
```

I have searched online and everything I find has made me feel like I am very very close, but the data is not binding. I have also set breakpoints in the CompanyViewModel and they aren't being hit, even when the view changes which is very strange. Maybe I am missing something obvious but I am at my wits end with this application lol. Can someone assist or point me in another direction?

Comment: You shouldn't be loading companies in your `CompanyViewModel`. It should only handle displaying a `CompanyModel`.

Comment: You have not shown how exactly that UserControl is used. Make sure its DataContext is set to the value of `CompanyVM` property of `_mainViewModel`.

Comment: As a note, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the Companies Binding is pointless. UpdateSourceTrigger only affects TwoWay or OneWayToSource Bindings.

Comment: I build a demo based on your example. You may find some of it useful https://github.com/SirRufo/so-76534237